# all transform make the mesh split far from each other

Tags: mesh, sculpting, mirror

hey all so I m trying to create a face mesh , but whenever I try apply all transform , the half of the face split to the other way far? as it shown in the picture , also the other mesh which is the lips also split half when ever I try to apply transform for the face? even though the lips mesh is a whole different mesh not one object... any help please? what am I missing here

thanks in advance[image]

blend:"[image]

Comment: Could you check where is each mesh origin ? Using Blender 3.6.5, I am not sure your file was red correctly, but it seems that the lips origin is not on the symmetry plane of this object (as it should for the symmetry modifier to produce what you are expecting).

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the location, it brings back the object to the center of the scene. In the file you share if you apply the location of the face (called *Plane*) it will move it towards the center of the scene. As *Blue Realistic* uses *Plane* as *Mirror Object* and as *Plane* has moved, it changes *Blue Realistic* mirroring.

Answer (score 1):

It's because "Mirror Modifier" for mirroring uses object's Origin Point.

Applying "All Transforms" includes applying the object's location – because of that the origin point shifts to the zero coordinate – and mirroring continues using the zero coordinate as a mirror point.

That's the reason of your problem.

Solution is really simple:

Instead of applying "All Transforms" you can apply "Rotation & Scale" :

[Ctrl + A] —>  [Rotation & Scale]

That's it  :-)